# Empty value from CSV import (sqlalchemy) to Postgres numeric column appears blank

Tags: sql, database, pandas, csv, isnull

I imported a csv file via sqlalchemy to my postgres database using the create table with columns and attributes plus the copy-from method.

Now I have the following situation: I have empty cells from my csv file. In the database (which I visually access via SQL Workbench) I see that that there are empty cells - and the column specification is still numeric. However, as I have found so far, a numeric column cannot have empty / blank cells, but rather NULL.

On the other hand I tried to validate this via:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_a)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_a IS NULL;
```

which shows me 0 as a result; from which I infer that my empty appearing cells are not NULL.

The reason why I ask is: I would like to find all "real" 0s in my table and replace them either with empty / blank or the NULL (important is consistency here) because I need to stream data from the database and put a subset to a panda.dataframe; not sure how panda treats different formats of missing value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found indirectly the answer to the above question:
- empty value is treated in Postgres as NULL, in SQL Workbench you see empty cells though
- Count(Column) skips NULL so and will never count empty cells ([Stackoverflow: validate-if-a-column-has-a-null-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771265/validate-if-a-column-has-a-null-value)

Comment: Did you try `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: I didn't use the star because I have way more columns in the table which also have NULL values